# Convert Decimal to Hex using Recursive method Java, without using Strings, java.utils and switch

Tags: java, recursion, hex

Additional conditions:

1)Don’t use strings working with digits in numbers.

2)don't use jdk utils and if/switch to map A-F letters.

it is last piece of task:

Write a recursive function for transfer of natural numbers from the decimal system in the N-ary. The value N in the main program is entered from the keyboard (16 >= N >= 2).

import java.util.Scanner;

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Insert number ");
    int number = s.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Insert Base");
    int n = s.nextInt();
    System.out.println(convertFromDecimalToBaseN(number, n, 1));


}

public static Integer convertFromDecimalToBaseN(int num, int n, int pow) { //pow always = 1;
        Integer r = num % n;

        if (num < n)
            return new Double((Math.pow(10, pow - 1)) * r.doubleValue()).intValue();

        return convertFromDecimalToBaseN(num / n, n, pow + 1) +
                new Double(Math.pow(10, pow - 1) * r.doubleValue()).intValue();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors, where are you getting stuck ? ... please add more information, and fix the code indentation to include your 'import' statement into the code blcok

Comment: And what is your question? If your code is not working, specify expected and actual output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a table lookup for the A-F letters like so

```
private static char charMap[] = {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6',
                        '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'};

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Insert number ");
    int number = s.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Insert Base");
    int n = s.nextInt();
    System.out.println(convertFromDecimalToBaseN(number, n, ""));
}

public static String convertFromDecimalToBaseN(int num, int n, String result) {
    int r = num % n;
    int rest = num / n;

    if (rest > 0) {
        return convertFromDecimalToBaseN(rest, n, charMap[r] + result);
    }

    return charMap[r] + result;
}
```